# Find a string by searching all stored procs in SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Is there a way to search for a string within all stored procs in SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE definition LIKE '%yourstring%'
```

Comment: @gbn: Thanks, now i'm wondering if I should add in my answer that `sys.sql_modules` is the only view that has the definition as a `NVARCHAR(MAX)` instead of `NVARCHAR(4000)`

Comment: To also get the name of the stored procedure:
SELECT p.name, m.* FROM sys.sql_modules m INNER JOIN sys.procedures p on m.object_id = p.object_id WHERE definition LIKE '%SEARCHSTRING%'

Comment: Another way to get the name _without_ a join would be to call OBJECT_NAME: `SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id), * FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE definition LIKE '%search%'`, [starting with SQL Server 2008](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-name-transact-sql).

Answer (score 23):

Have a look at [**RedGate's SQL Search**](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/).  It's a Management Studio plugin and a free download.  You can search within a given database or across an entire instance.

Answer (score 22):

I always use this;

```
SELECT Name
 FROM sys.procedures
 WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%SEARCHSTRING%'
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was looking to get the schema and the name of the stored procedure whenever I search for a specific text or keyword. The code I use and it is working for me is:

```
USE [your_DB_name];
GO
SELECT [Scehma]=schema_name(o.schema_id), o.Name 
FROM sys.sql_modules m
 INNER JOIN sys.objects o
ON o.object_id = m.object_id
WHERE m.definition like '%your keyword%'
GO
```

The result is simple and as follows:

```
----------------------------------------------
|    Schema    |    Name                     |
----------------------------------------------
|    dbo       |  stored_procedure_name      |
----------------------------------------------
...
and so on (if the keyword exists in more than one stored procedure)
```